# Anylogic problem: two different agents with two different service's time

Tags: java, anylogic

I’m trying to resolve a simulation problem with anylogic but I don't know how to do it.

**This is the problem**: There are two different types of product, A and B, which arrive at one machine with different rates (40 per hour for the type A and 30 per hour for the type B), both type go in the same queue and next go into a machine (FIFO) which have a different service's time for the two product (1 minute for A and 2 minutes for B).

How can I modelize this problem with a simple flowchart block (eg. blocks agent, queue, delay and sink)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just create it the way you described it. If you want to turn it into 1 single flowchart block, right-click on everything as below and select "Create flowchart block".

[image]

To setup the different service times in the delay block, you can use code like this:
[image]
Obviously, your source objects need to create different agent types, "TypeA" and "TypeB" are just placeholders by me.

Comment: Thank you so much, in caso of the rates and the service's times are exponential distribuited how can I procede?

Comment: agent instanceof TypeA ? exponential(...)*minute() : exponential(...)*minute()

Comment: Sorry but in exponential(...) I need to insert the service time or another parameter (ex. The rate of service) because I proved to insert the service time and the resource with a major service time have less queue. Thank you!!!

Comment: sorry, not sure I follow. Is that a question, @GabrieleBontempi ? Can you clarify? :-)

Comment: In your function: agent instanceof TypeA ? exponential(X)*minute() : exponential(Y)*minute() what do I insert in place of X and Y? Do I insert the service time (expressed in minutes to the piece) or rate of service (pieces to the minute)??